# Date only change format when click twice at cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to format a date using

```
   Dim dt As Range
For Each dt In Range("A1:A1000")
    dt.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
Next dt
```

Some dates doesn't change

but when I click twice the dates receive the format, 
sometimes it happens with values too, what's going on ?

[image]

Comment: First - note that dates are serialized numbers in excel. Sounds like some of your values are `strings` masquerading as actual dates. You cannot apply date (number) formats to a string. Check if your values are all numbers using `ISTEXT(Cell)`

Comment: but they need to be numbers to work ?

Comment: Yes.`Numbers <> Strings representing Numbers`

Comment: In short, look up how to convert strings to numbers in `VBA`. There are many ways like `Text To Columns`, adding 0, etc. Once you correct that, your existing code should work

Answer (score 0):

Please test this against your data.

```
Sub test()
   Dim dt As Range
    For Each dt In Range("A1:A1000")
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(dt) Then
            dt.Value = Val(dt.Value)
        End If
            dt.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Next dt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop here **unless** you only need to update the format conditionally

1. Declare range (`dt`)
2. Convert `dt` to values *(only applies to strings presented
   as numbers)*
3. Apply desired format to `dt` *(all cells at once, not loop)*

---

```
Sub All_At_Once()

Dim dt As Range: Set dt = Range("A1:A1000")
dt.Value = dt.Value
dt.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

End Sub
```